# How can i make my checkbox and input search to be inline?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react material ui library

https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/

I need to have form group with checkbox and input type search inside. So i use the two components
from this library

```
 <FormControl id="inline-form-group">
                <FormLabel component="legend">Choose Columns:</FormLabel>
                <FormGroup>
                    <FormControlLabel
                        control={<Checkbox checked={gilad} onChange={handleCheckboxesChange} name="gilad" />}
                        label="Gilad Gray"
                    />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                    <TextField id="standard-search" label="Column value" type="search" />
                </FormGroup>
            </FormControl>
```

but now textfield is under the checkbox

I want to have them inline.

I can't find in their documentation option like this

Answer (score 1):

In the label position of your FormControlLabel you could put in your TextField.
This would work if you don't need to have the Gilad Gray as your curretn label.

````
<FormControlLabel
    control={<Checkbox checked={true} onChange={handleChange} name="jason" />}
    label={<TextField />}
/>
    ```
````